# Why is the tab-order "backwards" when tabbing over Java components inside a JPanel inside a matlab figure?

Tags: java, matlab, focus, traversal

By running this matlab code example and tabbing through components, you can see how traversing through the Java components on a matlab figure (added with 
javacomponent) does not behave as expected. Please, if anyone has any insight on how to make the tab-order behave properly I would appreciate it :)

```
function hfig = testJavaFocus
% Illustration of tab-order focus problem.
% Run this and start hitting tab. Observe that tab-order goes "backwards"
% when traversing through the components in the JPanel. WHY!!!??!?!?!?

hfig = figure;
components = [];

%% Add JTextField
text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
components{end+1} = text;

%% Add JTextField
text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
components{end+1} = text;

%% Add JPanel - we will add 3 components to this panel to illustrate focus problem
panel = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JPanel');
panel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.GREEN);

text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
panel.add(text);
text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
panel.add(text);
text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
panel.add(text);

components{end+1} = panel;

%% Add JTextField
text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
components{end+1} = text;

%% Add JTextField
text = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JTextField',6);
text.setFocusable(true);
components{end+1} = text;

%% Add all components to the figure via javacomponent()
x = 10;
padding = 3;
for i = 1:length(components)
   prefDim = components{i}.getPreferredSize();
   widpos = [x,10,prefDim.width,prefDim.height];
   [jh, hg] = javacomponent(components{i},widpos,hfig);
   x = x + prefDim.width + padding;
end

end
```

Comment: I have also seen this before... AFAIK the answer lies within this: `why(70)`

Comment: There is a matlab built-in function that might help resolve this problem. Try `uistack`, see for the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html).